# trying to understand this function pattern

Tags: javascript

So im trying to write a function pattern which creates the following pattern upto n number of rows. If the Argument is 0 or a Negative Integer then it should return "" i.e. empty string.

```
123456
23456
3456
456
56
6
```

I am trying to understand the solution of this question as below:

```
function pattern(n){  
 var output="";   
   for(i=1;i<n+1;i++){ 
     for(j=i;j<n+1;j++){    //what is the purpose of this j loop? 
       output += j;   
     }
     if(i!=n) output +="\n";   //I know \n can jump to next line,  but what does this if statement mean?  why I!=n? 
   }
 return output;
}
```

Comment: The j loop controls where to start the current line numbers.  The i loop controls how many rows.  The final if statement means don't add a newline on the final row.

Answer (score 2):

```
// function definition
function pattern(n){  
 // declare a variable to collect the lines
 var output="";
   // there are n lines
   for(i=1;i<n+1;i++){ 
     // each line starts with the linenumber and ends with n
     // so take a loop from i to n
     for(j=i;j<n+1;j++){
       // collect the numbers of each line as a string in the declared variable 
       output += j;   
     }
     // if i!=n means: not the last line
     if(i!=n) output +="\n";
   }
 // return the result of this function
 return output;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

But please let me point out, that the given solution is not very smart. Take a look at the following code:

```
Array.range = function(start, end) {
    return Array.apply(null, Array(end+1)).map(function (_, i) {return i;}).slice(start);
}

function pattern(n){
    var startValues = Array.range(1,n);
    return startValues.map(function(i) { return Array.range(i,n); }).join('\n');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afmchdwp/

First we define the static Method Array.range which helps us to define number ranges in javascript.

The pattern function can now use this ranges to create the numbers you need.
The first line of the function create a range from 1..n (the startnumbers of the lines).

The second line walks throu this array and transform every value 1..n into a range from the linenumber to n. With .join(), you can combine the characters of each line and combine the lines itself.

**UPDATE 2**

Here a updated fiddle without comma separated numbers (using join inside the closure): http://jsfiddle.net/afmchdwp/1/